# Hashmap not populating

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to populate `Hashmap` as following:

```
public static final String KEY_PROPNAME = "";
public static final String KEY_KEYWORDS = "";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URI = "";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> clipsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < clipDetailsArr.length; i = i
            + constants.noOfColumns) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(KEY_PROPNAME, clipDetailsArr[i]);
        map.put(KEY_PROPTYPE, clipDetailsArr[i + 1]);
        map.put(KEY_PRICE, clipDetailsArr[i + 2]);
        map.put(KEY_LOCATION, clipDetailsArr[i + 3]);
        map.put(KEY_SQFT, clipDetailsArr[i + 4]);
        map.put(KEY_SQFTTYPE, clipDetailsArr[i + 5]);
        map.put(KEY_BED, clipDetailsArr[i + 6]);
        map.put(KEY_BATH, clipDetailsArr[i + 7]);
        map.put(KEY_KEYWORDS, clipDetailsArr[i + 8]);
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URI, clipDetailsArr[i + 9]);

        Log.i("Main", "Clip clipDetailsArr[]: 0=" + clipDetailsArr[i] + " ,1=" + clipDetailsArr[i + 1]
                + " ,2=" + clipDetailsArr[i + 2] + " ,3=" + clipDetailsArr[i + 3] + " ,4="
                + clipDetailsArr[i + 4] + " ,5=" + clipDetailsArr[i + 5] + " ,6="
                + clipDetailsArr[i + 6] + " ,7=" + clipDetailsArr[i + 7] + " ,8="
                + clipDetailsArr[i + 8] + " ,9=" + clipDetailsArr[i + 9]);

        Log.i("Main", "Clip PROPNAME=" + MainActivity.KEY_PROPNAME
                + " ,KEYWORDS" + MainActivity.KEY_KEYWORDS + " ,URI="
                + MainActivity.KEY_THUMB_URI);

        Log.i("Main", "Clip get PROPNAME=" + map.get(KEY_PROPNAME)
                + " ,KEYWORDS" + map.get(KEY_KEYWORDS) + " ,URI="
                + map.get(KEY_THUMB_URI));          
        clipsList.add(map);
    }
```

Output of log is something like this:

```
Clip clipDetailsArr[]: 0=Opt out ,1=Residentail ,2=10000 ,3=Andheri ,4=500 ,5=Carpet ,6=2 ,7=1 ,8=optout ,9=/mnt/sdcard/Clipping/optout.png

Clip PROPNAME= ,KEYWORDS ,URI=

Clip get PROPNAME=/mnt/sdcard/Clipping/optout.png,
         KEYWORDS/mnt/sdcard/Clipping/optout.png,
         URI=/mnt/sdcard/Clipping/optout.png//AND SO ON
```

Referring to above log, I have values in my array and I'm putting them into array by using `map.put(key,value)` but in 2nd log `MainActivity.KEY_PROPNAME` and other fields are empty. Also, when I use `map.get(key)`, all the column have data of last column.

Note that last column data is getting populated appropriately.

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same key `""` for at least three `.put()` !! You have defined :

```
public static final String KEY_PROPNAME = "";
public static final String KEY_KEYWORDS = "";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URI = "";
```

And then you populate the `Map` as :

```
map.put(KEY_PROPNAME, clipDetailsArr[i]);
map.put(KEY_KEYWORDS, clipDetailsArr[i + 8]);
map.put(KEY_THUMB_URI, clipDetailsArr[i + 9]);
```

As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,V%29):

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Comment: .. and a HashMap replaces with .put() each occurrence

Comment: Oh gosh. I can't believe I made such a stupid (and silly !) mistake. Thanks a ton buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String KEY_PROPNAME = "";
public static final String KEY_KEYWORDS = "";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URI = "";
```

Here all of your keys have same value/name, Hence all the data will store in the same key !!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String KEY_PROPNAME = "";
public static final String KEY_KEYWORDS = "";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URI = "";
```

This is the error, instead of creating empty strings from your name you should use them as the Keys to get your requested behavior.

Just to keep your code almost the same you could to something like:

```
public static final String KEY_PROPNAME = "KEY_PROPNAME";
public static final String KEY_KEYWORDS = "KEY_KEYWORDS";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URI = "KEY_THUMB_URI";
```

That should to the trick even if it is a little funky ;)

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that.